How to Detect the Position of a Webview in VS Code After It Has Been Dragged？
I am developing a VS Code extension that provides a webview in the sidebar. The webview is created using vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider. Users can drag the webview from the sidebar to the panel, and I need to detect its new position (whether it's in the sidebar or the panel).
My ultimate goal is to provide a shortcut key to hide the webview, and for this, I need to know where the webview is currently located.
